# Highlight words as they are being spoken with google text-to-speech

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I`m making a web app using react and want to highlight the words as they are being spoken, using google text-to-speech. I know that with native speech synthesis API, you can use onboundary event. Is there a similar way you can do this with google tts?